# I keep running into a decode error and i have no idea how to fix it

Tags: python, utf-8, export-to-csv

So im trying to find a way to mass analyse a huge number of .csv files the code will work for 52 of the files or 125 of the files but wil lthen always run into the same error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 
316: ordinal not in range(128)
```

i have no idea why it works only for a specific number of the files and dont have a clue how to fix it, ive looked at prior posts and it seems to be something to do with either encoding or decoding with UTF-8 but anywhere i add it to the code i get more error saying that decoding/encoding with utf-8 isnt an atribute.

Ive added the code below, any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

```
os.chdir('PATH TO FILES')

for f in os.listdir():
    #try:
        with open(f) as csvfile:
            readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

            listReset()

            for row in readCSV:
                xr = row[3]
                yr = row[4]

                xaxis.append(float(xr))
                yaxis.append(float(yr))

        v1 = yaxis[0]
        vl = yaxis[-1]

        del yaxis[0]
        del yaxis[-1]

        sm = sum(yaxis)
```

Comment: Your code seems fine (assuming `listReset` is not the problem), so it's probably more related to the specific files you get the error for. Could you maybe provide a minimal example of a file for which this fails?

Comment: If you don't know the character encoding of your files, you have data loss. Once you do know, you have to apply that information when reading the files. Can you ask the source or get documentation from the source or listen to metadata channels such as HTTP Response header Content-Type when fetching the files from the source? Or, don't use any type of text file or other file that requires maintaining external metadata? There a plenty of good data document formats that don't suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i think what was happening was a formatting error, I've added a try and except statement and i skips one of the .csv files turns out it was corrupted, probably should've tried this first and now i feel stupid...

Comment: The byte value 0xff is not part of any formatting that I know of. Please edit your question to add ten or so bytes before and after the 0xff. It's a strong indicator that the file is not currupt but instead uses a different file encoding. In fact, text files are rarely encoded with ASCII.